# Jasper report syntax reportelement and frame

Tags: java, xml, jasper-reports, frame, report

I'm trying to understand how jasper reports work but i find the syntax a little difficult to get to grips with.

what exactly does reportelement- key refer to? also is frame a purely visual component?

```
<frame>
    <reportElement key="frame-6" mode="Opaque" x="0" y="36" width="534" height="36" backcolor="#CCCCCC"/>
    <box>
        <topPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
        <leftPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
        <bottomPen lineWidth="0.0" lineColor="#000000"/>
        <rightPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
    </box>
</frame>
```

Also in the following what do the F and v indicate, and more importantly where are they defined?

```
<textFieldExpression class="java.math.BigDecimal"><![CDATA[$V{amountTotal}]]></textFieldExpression>
<variableExpression><![CDATA[new BigDecimal($F{amount percentage})</variableExpression>
```

Answer (score 3):

**About the frame:**

The quotes from IReport Ultimate Guide:

> A frame is an element that can contain other elements and optionally
>   draw a border around them. 
>   
> ..
>   Since a frame is a container of other
>   elements, in the document outline view the frame is represented as a
>   node containing other elements. 
>   
> ..
>   A frame can contain other frames, and
>   so on recursively. To add an element to a frame, just drag the new
>   element from the palette inside the frame. Alternatively you can use
>   the outline view and drag elements from a band into the frame and so
>   on. The position of an element is always relative to the container
>   position. If the container is a band, the element position will be
>   relative to the top of the band and the left margin. If the container
>   (or element parent) is a frame, the element coordinates will be
>   relative to the top left corner of the frame. Since an element dragged
>   from a container to another does not change its top/left properties,
>   when moving an element from a container to another its position is
>   recalculated based on the new container location.
>   The advantages of using a frame to draw a border around a set of
>   elements, with respect to using a simple rectangle element, are: 
>   
>   * When you move a frame, all the elements contained in the frame will
>   move in concert. 
>   
>   * While using a rectangle to overlap some elements,
>   the elements inside the rectangle will not treated as overlapped
>   (respect to the frame), so you will not have problems when exporting in HTML (which does not support overlapped elements).
>   
>   * Finally, the frame will automatically stretch accordingly to its
>   content, and the element position type property of its elements will
>   refer to the frame itself, not to the band, making the design a bit
>   easier to manage.
>   in HTML (which does not support overlapped elements).

**About the reportElement**

The quotes from JasperReports Ultimate Guide:

> **REPORT ELEMENT PROPERTIES**
>   
>   When you add a report element to one of your report sections, you must
>   specify the relative position of this element in that particular
>   section and its size, along with other general report element
>   properties like color, transparency, stretch behavior, and so forth.
>   
>   The properties that are common to all types of report elements are
>   grouped in the  tag, which appears in the declaration
>   of all report elements.
>   
> ..
>   **ELEMENT KEY**
>   
>   Unlike variables and parameters, report elements are not
>   required to have a name, because normally you do not need to obtain
>   any individual element inside a report template. However, in some
>   cases it is useful to be able to locate an element to alter one of its
>   properties before using the report template. This could be the case in
>   an application for which the color of some elements in the report
>   template needs to change based on user input. To locate the report
>   elements that need to have their colors altered, the caller program
>   could use the getElementByKey(String) method available at band level.
>   A key value must be associated with the report element and it must be
>   unique within the overall band for the lookup to work. The key
>   attribute is used as an example in the provided
>   /demo/samples/alterdesign sample.

**About the fields ($F) and variables ($V):**

- `$F{fieldName}` is a reference to the field with name `fieldName`. The fields contains data from a `data source`.
- `$V{variableName}` is a reference to the report's variable with name `variableName`. The variable have expression and can be used for different calculations.